# What is happening on an atomic level (or lower) when a object is in motion (inertia)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, momentum, field-theory, inertia

If you have an iron ball and throw it upwards you are imparting a force which opposes gravity.

Initially this force is easily understood by your hand pushing the ball upwards, so the atoms in your hand are in contact with the atoms in the ball, and this sets the ball in motion.

At a certain point the ball leaves your hand and keeps travelling upwards, the hand is no longer imparting a force on the ball and as the ball is iron there is no relevant elasticity to account for (I assume).

This affect is described mathematically through Newtons laws and lexically as "inertia". It is understood that however much force was applied to the object before "take off" will be "contained" or held by the object until other forces (such as gravity and air resistance) oppose the momentum to the point it starts to fall.

My question is when the ball has taken off and is opposing the gravitational force of the Earth what is now moving the ball upwards on an atomic (or lower level). Or how can the force that is apparently contained in the ball be understood to exist in relation to the other forces acting upon it, such as gravity or air resistance.

Comment: There is no force of gravity acting on an object in free fall. Air resistance at the microscopic level are microscopic collisions that are transferring momentum from the object to air molecules.

Comment: I'm not talking about free fall I'm talking about the upwards part of the motion.

Comment: Guesser ! welcome to physics  exchange; when you ask (as in the title) - do you mean quantum mechanics might be included? since quantum mechanics is is the scale of atoms ? (if so, maybe add the tag)

Comment: @WilliamMartens anything non mathematical or general labelling like "inertia" is fine, I will add the QM tag.

Comment: @Guesser oh I see okay; right yea

Comment: Even upwards motion without external forces is free fall.

Comment: Ok fine, but gravity is acting on the object, I accept this is may not be described by physicist as a force. The point is gravity is opposing the force i.e pulling the object back down.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but it is almost as though there is less gravitational effect produced beneath the ball, like a moving pocket in the gravitational field. Or some kind of elasticity in the gravitational field itself.

Comment: We call "free fall" every motion under the gravitational force without friction. It does not matter if it has an initial velocity. There is no"force that is apparently contained in the ball" inertia just says velocity of a mass can only change if a force is applied, here the gravitational force after leaving the hand. the mean velocitty of all atoms in the ball is the velocity of the ball,

Comment: Gravity is simply not a force. That was already understood in the time of Newton. They just couldn't quite figure out what it is.